# Does a setfable nthcdr implementation exist?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am using clisp and I wonder if there is any library with a setfable version of nthcdr that I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hack around it with:

```
(let ((lst (list 1 2 3 4))
      (n 2))
  (setf (cdr (nthcdr (1- n) lst)) '(5 6 7))
  l)
> (1 2 5 6 7)
```

Or define your own setf for it:

```
;; !!warning!!  only an example, lots of nasty edge cases
(defsetf nthcdr (n lst) (new-val) 
   `(setf (cdr (nthcdr (1- ,n) ,lst)) ,new-val))
```

I do not know why nthcdr does not have a setf defined.  Even [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html) seems to define setf for last, but not nthcdr.

PS. I would treat wanting to setf an nthcdr as a bad smell in your code.

Comment: Why is it a bad smell? Especially when you imply that there is no reason not to have a setfable nthcdr defined.

Comment: The reason I want it is that I want to inject each node of a sexp with an id element and at the same time store each node in a hash-table while traversing the sexp tree. So if the decoration doesnt happen in-place, the values in the hash-table wont see the decorated subnodes

Comment: Note that in general in Common Lisp it is not defined what happens when you modify literal data.

Comment: I did not want to imply there is a good reason not to setf nthcdr, unfortunate phrasing from my part. 
Couldn't you do what you want with a recursive function and/or loop? Especially if you are doing multiple things at once for each node you traverse.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defsetf my-nthcdr (n list) (store)
  (let ((tmp (gensym)))
    `(let ((,tmp (nthcdr (1- ,n) ,list)))
       (rplacd ,tmp ,store)
       (cdr ,tmp))))
```

Doesn't work when n is 0 though, you could make it work when LIST is a symbol, checking if N is zero either on macroexpansion time, but then it only works if N is a number, or including the check in the expanded code.